# Creating multiple textboxes in powerpoint corresponding to lines of a text file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

So I have a *.txt file, and I would like to create a separate textbox in a powerpoint file corresponding to each line. Is there a way to do this in some kind of automatic / programmatic way?

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody is going to write this up for you as an answer, but I will start you off. You need to look at using VBA, the FileSystemObject and how to write code to create Shapes. If those things sound scary, walk away. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.